# execvp failing with multiple or no arguments

Tags: c, shell, arguments, exec, execvp

I'm working on a pretty basic UNIX shell in C. In this project I am attempting to use `fork()` and `execvp()` to execute the actual shell commands. I'm running into an issue though, where it seems to work fine with commands that have a single argument (for example `ls -l` and `echo howareyoutoday` work perfectly), but commands with multiple arguments fail to execute (`echo how are you today` does not run). I'll walk you through my code/rationale in an effort to help locate the reason behind this problem.

```
                char *token;
                int count=0;
                pid_t childProc;
                int childStatus;
                pid_t tpid;
                char* argv[256];
                int i=1;

                        childProc = fork();

                            if (childProc==0) {
                                    //CHILD PROCESS IS HERE
                                    argv[0] = malloc(strlen(token));
                                    argv[0] = token;

                                    token=strtok(NULL," \n\t()<>|&;");
                                    while(token!=NULL) {
                                            argv[i]=malloc(strlen(token));
                                            argv[i]=token;
                                            token=strtok(NULL," \n\t()<>|&;");
                                            i++;
                                    }
                                    execvp(argv[0],argv);

                                    //if this executes execvp fails
                                    printf("failure to execute\n");
                                    i=0;
                                    exit(0);
                            }
                            else {
                                    //PARENT PROCESS IS HERE
                                    do {
                                            tpid = wait(&childStatus);
                                    } while(tpid != childProc);
                            }
```

So it starts out with a basic `fork()` call to create the child process. In that child process, I allocate memory for the first element in my `argv` array. `token` which comes from a previous `strtok` call is assigned to `argv[0]`. A new `token` is generated and added to the next `argv` element. This process is repeated for the remaining tokens remaining.

Once the `argv` array has been completed, `execvp` is called, with the first argument containing the command name, and the second being the whole `argv` array. If the command fails to execute, `execvp` will return and a message indicating this will be printed.

I can't figure out why I am having the multiple arguments problem I mentioned above. Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

For reference, the full program's code is as follows:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[256];
    char *token;
    int count=0;
    pid_t childProc;
    int childStatus;
    pid_t tpid;
    char* argv[256];
    int i=1;
    int j=0;

    while(1) {
            fgets(buffer, 256, stdin);

            token=strtok(buffer," \n\t()<>|&;");

            while (token==NULL) {
                    fgets(buffer,256,stdin);
                    token=strtok(buffer," \n\t()<>|&;");
            }

                    if (strcmp(token,"exit")==0) {
                            exit(0);
                    }
                    else if (strcmp(token,"cd")==0) {
                            token = strtok(NULL, " \n\t()<>|&;");

                            if (chdir(token)!=0) {
                                    perror("Error: ");
                            }
                    }
                    else {
                            childProc = fork();

                            if (childProc==0) {
                                    argv[0] = malloc(strlen(token));
                                    argv[0] = token;

                                    token=strtok(NULL," \n\t()<>|&;");
                                    while(token!=NULL) {
                                            argv[i]=malloc(strlen(token));
                                            argv[i]=token;
                                            token=strtok(NULL," \n\t()<>|&;");
                                            i++;
                                    }
                                    execvp(argv[0],argv);

                                    //if this executes execvp fails
                                    printf("failure to execute\n");
                                    i=0;
                                    exit(0);
                            }
                            else {
                                    do {
                                            tpid = wait(&childStatus);
                                    } while(tpid != childProc);
                            }
                    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to null terminate your argument strings to `execvp`.

```
if (childProc == 0)
{
    argv[0] = malloc(strlen(token));
    argv[0] = token;

    token = strtok(NULL, " \n\t()<>|&;");

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        argv[i] = malloc(strlen(token));
        argv[i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " \n\t()<>|&;");
        i++;
    }

    argv[i] = NULL;  //<--- insert here

    if (execvp(argv[0], argv) == -1)
    {
        printf("failure to execute because %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(0);
    }
}
```